# Rails 5.0 Chapter 14 Micheal Hartl Tutorial undefined local variable active_relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, relationship, railstutorial.org

Basically I've been following the Rails tutorial(I've had a lot of issues but most of them were easy to tackle down) but right I now I've just begun the chapter and I'm running in a issue.

Here is the [link](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users) to the tutorial(after table 14.1 exercise 2), I'm currently blocked at the exercise since a variable isn't defined.

```rb
irb(main):035:0> active_relationship.follower \r
NameError: undefined local variable or method `active_relationship' for main:Object 
from (irb):35
```

I don't understand exactly what I'm doing however I know that we're trying out the relationships we created through `has_many:` and `belongs_to:`, creating the relationship works.

```rb
irb(main):021:0> user.active_relationships.create!(followed_id: 2)\r
       (0.1ms)  begin transaction
      User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
      User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
      SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "relationships" ("follower_id", "followed_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["follower_id", 1], ["followed_id", 2], ["created_at", 2017-06-27 20:49:11 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-06-27 20:49:11 UTC]]
       (57.3ms)  commit transaction
    => #<Relationship id: 1, follower_id: 1, followed_id: 2, created_at: "2017-06-27 20:49:11", updated_at: "2017-06-27 20:49:11">
```

Here is the content of the files freshly created :

app/models/relationship.rb

```rb
class Relationship < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"
end
```

app/models/user.rb

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :active_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
           foreign_key: "follower_id",
           dependent: :destroy
 .
 .
 .
```

The problem is here : I don't understand why the variable(`active_relationship`) is not defined but inside the console calling Relationships.all shows this:

```rb
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Relationship id: 1, follower_id: 1, followed_id: 2, created_at: "2017-06-27 20:49:11", updated_at: "2017-06-27 20:49:11">]>
```

It thus means that the relationship was created and is stored, thus it should be accessible through the methods, `active_relationship.followed` and `active_relationship.follower`.
But they are not defined and I don't know why they're not.
If more information is needed just ask for it, I'll be glad if it could help me resolve this little issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either access to the elements of your relationships by using `user.active_relationships` which is an array of relationships (follower / followed relations) or you can store the result of `user.active_relationships.create` as the `active_relationship`.

Your issue is that `active_relationship` is undefined in your context, the tutorial must have supposed that you stored this value based on the return value of `create` or by accessing the array of relationships.

Comment: I had the same problem and hadn't realised the solution was to _assign_ the returned value from the `create` action into the variable! The book reads like it's a _thing_. So, thanks for the response to this.